# Past Events Cannot displayed In Calendar Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using following  code for past events.Please tell me the Solution for Past Events

```
NSDate* endDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:endDate calendars:nil];
NSArray *eventList = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
NSLog(@"allevent:%@",eventList);
```

Comment: please Tell me the Solution

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below code

```
  NSDate *endDate =  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSDate distantFuture] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];

  NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:cal];

  NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate date] endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray];

  NSArray *eventList = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];

  for(int i=0; i < eventList.count; i++)
  {

    NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] title]);

  }
```

Comment: Not Working. Please tell me the different Solution

Comment: If you use this,what output do you get?

Comment: only Future Events Show.But past events Cannot displayed

Comment: where do you have  events?Is it in server or db for showing in calander?